# pre-compressed gzip break on chrome, why?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, gzip, google-chrome

I serve pre-compressed CSS and JS files on my site, and IE6-8 and FF
is working perfectly with my .htaccess file.

```
# Compressed files
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} .*gzip.*
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz
AddType application/x-javascript .gz
AddType text/css .gz
```

I call the files with the .gz extension already [example]:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/layout.css.gz" />
```

So why is this breaks in google Chrome?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and look at the raw response headers to see what the server is sending back for that particular request.

FYI, Fiddler is a client side proxy that filters your browser requests through. Super informative when dealing with these kind of issues.

**-- Update**

Upon further investigation, it doesn't appear that your RewriteCond is actually doing what you think it is doing. According to the [Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), the RewriteCond directive is only used in conjunction with a RewriteRule.

Answer (score 3):

1. You must use the `Content-Encoding: gzip` response header.
2. You must only return GZIP compressed content when the client's `Accept-Encoding` header allows **GZIP**.

Answer (score 3):

Our .htaccess file (we have .jsz files with compressed javascript, and Chrome handles them fine):

```
AddEncoding gzip .jsz
AddType text/javascript .jsz
```

Answer (score 3):

Safari (and Google Chrome) don`t works with compressed file if they extension is .gz

To support gzip archives on Safari and Chrome, copy and compress .css and .js files into gzip and rename they extension a .gz on the .jgz
(for example:
    before - one file style.css into directory
    after  - two files, style.css and style.css.jgz into directory )

And added this code into your .htaccess file:

```
AddEncoding gzip .jgz
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Safari
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Konqueror
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.jgz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.jgz [QSA,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent
    <FilesMatch .*\.js.jgz$>
    ForceType text/javascript
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
    Header set Cache-control: private
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch .*\.css.jgz$>
    ForceType text/css
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding  
    Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
    Header set Cache-control: private
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

For example [megaburg.ru](http://megaburg.ru/)
Tested - is working with Safari, Chrome, Opera and Firefox  8)

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question with a much more conservative matching rule for when to Gzip:

> Safari, Chrome, and IE6 all have
>   problems with Gzipped downloads. Also,
>   Apache will do the gzip compression
>   for you, there is no need to manually
>   gzip files.  Try this snippet:
>
> ```
> # This uses mod_deflate, which is pretty standard on Apache 2.  Loading
> # mod_deflate looks like this:
> #
> #   LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
> #
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
> BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
> BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
> BrowserMatch \\bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
> ```

See the original post: [How can I make my .htaccess file allow Safari & other browsers to open GZIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245889/htaccss-file-to-allow-safari-other-browsers-to-open-gzip/1245948#1245948)

Comment: i fail to see where your configuration will prevent gzip taking place for chrome browser...

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to set the `Content-Encoding` header field to tell the client, that the response data is encoded with gzip:

```
<FilesMatch "\.gz$">
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
</FilesMatch>
```

But unfortunatly Apache doesn’t allow to set that header field. Instead `Content-Encoding` will become `X-Content-Encoding`.

Comment: so what does that mean if it will become with X prefix?

Comment: It means that it will not be recognized.

Answer (score -2):

Google Chrome (and Apple Safari) do not support gzip compressed CSS and JavaScript. Certain IE6 versions also have problems.
They do support gzip compressed HTML documents, but not CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: how can I filter those who not support in my htaccess file ?

Comment: You shouldn't link to the .gz files directly from your HTML. You could use mod_rewrite or (even better) mod_negotiation so send the gzip compressed file instead.

Comment: or just yui compress them, which will give you valid JS and comparable compression savings

Comment: YUI compression is no where close to gzip compression. Usually you would also gzip the result of YUI.
See: http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/08/13/

Comment: yes, they are already compressed with Dean's PACKER, but GZIP
is by far the best solution. my server doesn't support GZIP on the fly..so I must pre-compressed them. mod_rewrite doesn't work.
even if it did, would it help in Chrome case?

Comment: I'm not sure if the Chrome/Safari comment is all that accurate as I am currently using GZip compressed CSS and Javascript successfully.

Comment: Untrue.  Current versions of Safari and all versions of Chrome support GZIP just fine.

Comment: Not for JavaScript and CSS. GZIPed HTML documents work just fine, but when the browser requests the linked javascript and css files it will drop the support for gzip (just check the request headers and you'll see).

Comment: This is simply not true. All JS/CSS requests in these browsers are sent with "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate". It's possible you have a proxy/antivirus that's munging this request header in order to more easily scan your JS/CSS files. Go to a site that lists your request headers and you'll probably see a header like "Accept-Enc!ding".

Comment: -1. Simply False. As an example yahoo.com serves gzipped stylesheets and javascript files and works fine in Google Chrome. I'll reconsider my vote if you prove you're right (for example referencing a reliable source)

Comment: @Andrea Zilio: that's probably because it has been fixed in recent Chrome versions. Up to and including Chrome 2.x did not like gzip compressed css/javascript files.
You should never rely on the user agent to serve gzip compressed files, always rely on the presence of "Accept-Encoding" containing either gzip or deflate.