# MediaWiki site display gzipped gibberish in Firefox and Chromium

Tags: firefox, gzip, mediawiki, shared-hosting

I have a MediaWiki site http://wiki.wubrowse.org/, on which I enabled file cache to increase respond speed. (instructions from http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:File_cache)

```
$wgUseFileCache = true; /* default: false */
$wgFileCacheDirectory = "$IP/cache";
$wgShowIPinHeader = false;
```

With this settings I didn't observe a faster response, like ~4s for page loading.

While when I enabled gzip:

```
$wgUseGzip = true;
```

I observe ~1s for page loading.
But this generated another issue that the site works well with Safari and Google Chrome, but display gibberish in Firefox and Chromium.

Did anyone have simillar experience and got a solution?
Many thanks.

Comment: your site works well for me in Chromium and Firefox. Can you be a bit more specific about the problem? Any error messages on the server? In the browser?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I need to disable this gzip feature as DreamHost told me they didn't support that. Thanks again. But I am getting the slow issue again.

Comment: It would be great if you managed to tell us what settings the webserver is using. The issue is often caused by MediaWiki's inability to correctly guess what the webserver is doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pre-compressed gzip break on chrome, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962721/pre-compressed-gzip-break-on-chrome-why)